# Is it frowned upon to report a one-tailed p value if you research question justifies it?

Tags: p-value

So, the questions I set out to find out in my research paper was does X increase when exposed to a certain stimulus. I only wanted to know the increase as I know it will not decrease when exposed to it based on my research. I only needed to know one side. My research is in psycholinguistics/psychology.

So, my question is, someone in another forum told me reporting one-sided p values is frowned upon though? Is this true? Could I not get something published if gave the p value one-sided?

Thanks so much

Comment: In medicine, it is considered good practice to half the alpha level for one-sided primary hypotheses. Of key importance is to specify the strategy during the planning of the study, not during analysis.

Comment: @MichaelM Yeah for my study I specified this up front as I'm only looking to see if their rate of something increases after seeing the target stimulus. I am not interested int he other side as I know the expected outcome based on the research. Would this be fine then?

Comment: As mentioned above, if it would be a medical study of some relevance, you would use an alpha level of 2.5% for your primary one-sided hypothesis. This has the advantage of corresponding to a 95% confidence *interval* as well as removing any doubts from the referees that you used the one-sided approach only to save sample size.